# Disk size and log file growth during upgrades

Tags: sql-server-2012, transaction-log, disk-space, vldb

I have four SQL Server databases. Per the maximum load requirements, each database file can be between 1 and 2 TB in size. The HDD is a multi-disk DAS with about 9TB of space. During a database upgrade, the transaction log file for a single database can grow up to 4TB in size. (yeah, I added a new column to a multi-billion row table.) The databases are on Simple Recovery model.

I can find no recommendation (or rule of thumb) from Microsoft about how much disk space I need for a given database size. I get that it can vary widely. If my understanding is correct, it's the largest transaction which I need to consider since space internal to the log file is re-used for different transactions. I think the log growth is set to 10%, but even if it were set to 1 or 2 Gig increments, I think I'd still be cutting it close.

Is there some strategy I need to employ to avoid such huge log files or do I simply need more disk space to avoid running out of space during an upgrade? If I'm doing something wrong, I want to learn how to do it the proper way.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Enterprise edition ? Also, can you tell us what version of sql server are you using - sql server 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 ?

Comment: Related discussion: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/adding-columns-to-production-tables

Comment: @Kin Oh sorry, I've updated the question to say 2012!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (yeah, I added a new column to a multi-billion row table.)

Adding a column to a very large table can have implications but there is a [clever way of adding column as well](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4536/8783).

From : [Adding NOT NULL Columns as an Online Operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

> Starting with SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, adding a NOT NULL column with a default value is an online operation when the default value is a runtime constant. This means that the operation is completed almost instantaneously regardless of the number of rows in the table.
>
> Adding a NOT NULL column with a default value that is not a runtime constant is always performed offline and an exclusive (SCH-M) lock is acquired for the duration of the operation.

Enterprise edition ([works on 2008 R2 standard edition as per comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1730868/1387418)) has `ALTER TABLE source_table SWITCH TO new_destination_table`

> The databases are on Simple Recovery model.

In simple recovery model, only a `CHECKPOINT` will truncate the log.

If you are recording autogrowth metrics during your typical upgrade, then an average of those collected metrics would give you a good starting figure. [**This script**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46686/8783) will help you get started *(you would need default trace enabled and running on your server)*.

> I think the log growth is set to 10%, but even if it were set to 1 or 2 Gig increments, I think I'd still be cutting it close.

I would suggest you to **change** the autogrowth setting from Percentage to Fixed MB. As [@AaronBertrand says in his comment :](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53899/8783)

> The problem is that it takes longer and longer over time, since 10% of a growing file is also constantly growing itself - it's like compound interest, but you're paying, not receiving.

For completeness, make sure you have Instant file initialization enabled, so the data file autogrowth can take advantage of it.

Comment: A thorough and quick answer - thanks! So would you say that I need to be squeezing what I can (within reason) from the DBMS before I throw my hands up and _sound the alarm_ about needing more disk space?

Comment: @colbybhearn yes. There are ways that I pointed out that you can leverage to minimize downtime as well as locking/blocking. You have to properly size your both data and log files, since autogrowth is an expensive event. SQL Server has to wait for that event to finish and then resume the work. A low value of autogrowth and a prematurely size database will have tons of autogrowth events kicked in thereby affecting the performance. Please feel free to upvote/accept as answer if this has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario of adding a column to a VLDB-class table, it may be worth  exploring creating a new table with the new structure and moving records from the old table to the new table in small ranges. It'll keep the individual transaction size small so the high-water mark for the Tlog in Simple recovery would be relatively low. You can't avoid ACID requirements altogether but if you can batch your upgrade as smaller steps instead of one single transaction, you may be able to work around the disk space constraint.

Comment: Ok, this a good example and explanation of what I figured (but couldn't formulate clearly) had to be one strategy for certain scenarios. Thanks!