# Add values from two existing column into new columns for a total

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have two existing columns in our database named 'ClientIncome' and 'PartnerIncome'. We would like to add a new column named 'HouseholdIncome'

We would like to add the values from 'ClientIncome' and 'PartnerIncome' into the new 'HouseholdIncome' column?

Here is a small example of our database.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Incomes](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientIncome] [float] NOT NULL,
    [PartnerIncome] [float] NULL,
    [HouseholdIncome] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Incomes] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Incomes] ([Id], [ClientIncome], [PartnerIncome], [HouseholdIncome]) VALUES (1, 130.77, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Incomes] ([Id], [ClientIncome], [PartnerIncome], [HouseholdIncome]) VALUES (2, 294.82, 339.28, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Incomes] ([Id], [ClientIncome], [PartnerIncome], [HouseholdIncome]) VALUES (3, 0, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Incomes] ([Id], [ClientIncome], [PartnerIncome], [HouseholdIncome]) VALUES (4, 0, 396.82, NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Incomes] OFF
GO
```

The table we would like to update has around 5 million rows, so any help with adding this new column would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that there are several existing questions about adding columns to large tables, including specifically for SQL Server (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/adding-columns-to-production-tables).  Arguably this question can stand alone, as the real solution is a computed column, but do please use the search feature before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change your table create statement to use a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Incomes](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientIncome] [float] NOT NULL,
    [PartnerIncome] [float] NULL,
    [HouseholdIncome] AS COALESCE(ClientIncome, 0.) + COALESCE(PartnerIncome, 0.)
)
```

If your table is already created, you can add a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Incomes ADD HouseholdIncome 
    AS COALESCE(ClientIncome, 0.) + COALESCE(PartnerIncome, 0.);
```

Comment: And if the values aren't likely to change often, you may want to consider making it `PERSISTED` to actually save the value to disk.